# load ntuser.dat hive with delphi

Tags: delphi, registry

I'd like to ask if anyone knows correct way how to load ntuser.dat file into registry on Windows7 or XP. I've been trying to accomplish that by using this code

```
_Reg := TRegistry.Create;
_Reg.RootKey := HKEY_USERS;
if (_Reg.Loadkey('Test2', 'C:\Users\Test2\NTUSER.DAT')) then
  ShowMessage('User hive loaded'); 
_Reg.Unloadkey('Test2');
_Reg.CloseKey;
_Reg.Free;
```

Path to a file is correct and file exists. I've also tried to use function I found on the internet [EnableNTPrivilege('SeRestorePrivilege', SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=129564) for setting up privileges before trying to load a hive. And still I get false from _Reg.Loadkey.

I've also tried to use this function [NTSetPrivilege('SeRestorePrivilege', True)](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1177) for setting up privileges. But this function returns error 'Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller'

Comment: Are you running elevated? And please tell us what the error is.

Comment: When i run my project executable as admin, i don't get error, but 'User hive loaded' message still doesn't show up...

Comment: Windows returns error codes when api calls fail. What error code is being returned?

Comment: Error code returned: 1300. But as I said, error doesn't show up if I run my exe as admin

Comment: If LoadKey fails then there must be an error

Comment: tried catching exceptions and no exception is thrown... LoadKey just returns 0 which indicates false of course...

Comment: you  must set the SE_RESTORE_NAME and SE_BACKUP_NAME privileges of you process before to use the `LoadKey` function.

Comment: Also the error code returned by the registry operations are stored in the `TRegistry.LastError` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`TRegistry.LoadKey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.LoadKey) function internally uses the [`RegLoadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which requieres that the calling process have the SE_RESTORE_NAME and SE_BACKUP_NAME privileges. If the call to the function returns a value <> to `ERROR_SUCCESS (0)` you must check the  [`LastError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.LastError)  and the [`LastErrorMsg`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.LastErrorMsg) properties to get more info.

Check this sample to see how the function must be called and how the result of the operation is handled.

```
var
 Reg : TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    NTSetPrivilege('SeRestorePrivilege', True); //this is a third-party function, you can implemnt your own to set the privileges.
    NTSetPrivilege('SeBackupPrivilege', True);
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_USERS;
    if (Reg.Loadkey('Test2', 'C:\Users\Test2\NTUSER.DAT')) then
    begin
      try
        Reg.OpenKey('Test2', False);
        try
            //do your stuff here


        finally
          Reg.CloseKey;
        end;
      finally
       Reg.Unloadkey('Test2');
      end;
    end
    else
      Writeln(Reg.LastErrorMsg);
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working on Delphi, now I am wondering why it doesn't work on Lazarus

Comment: Nevermind, found out. As long as Lazarus is cross-platform they don't intend implementing LoadKey, Savekey, ReplaceKey and some other functions, because they can't guarantee cross-platform portable results

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* way to load and manipulate a specific user's Registry hive is to having your calling thread impersonate that user (if the thread is not already running as that user) and then use [`RegOpenCurrentUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894.aspx), [`RegOpenUserClassesRoot()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724899.aspx), and/or [`LoadUserProfile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281.aspx) as needed.